# App shows no devices supported in play store on update

Tags: android, react-native

uploaded the APK file to Google Play and says supported devices is 0. Previously I have uploaded the build and wasn't getting this warning. I have added `DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION`, `USE_BIOMETRIC`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions and now getting the warning.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="***********************"/>
  <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
   android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
   
  <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
     </intent-filter>
  </service>

  <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />

</application>
```